# Function scope within IF Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

hoping some one can shed some light on my problem. Basicly I only want to execute a block of code if a certain DOM element exists. If it does I then perform a few bits and bobs and then call a function. However it complains that the function is not defined, suggesting that the function is not in scope. Below is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function ()  
        {   
        if ((document.getElementById("view<portlet:namespace/>:editSplash")!= null)) {
        console.log("notifications scripted started");  

        // hide loading box/ notify on body load  
        $('.ajaxErrorBox').hide();
        $('.loadingNotifications').hide();
        $('.notifyWindow').hide();
        getFeed();

        // set up refresh button for reloading feed
        $('.refreshFeed').click(function() {
        $('.notifyWindow').hide();
        $('.notifyWindow').empty();
        console.log("notifications clicked");
        getFeed(); 
        });

    // begin ajax call using jquery ajax object 

    function getFeed ()
    {
    $('.notifyWindow').empty();  
    console.log("ajax call for feed starting");
        $.ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://cw-pdevprt-05.tm-gnet.com:10040/notificationsweb/feed?username=uid=<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/engine.tld" prefix="wps" %><wps:user attribute="uid"/>",
        dataType: "text/xml",
        timeout: 10000,
        success: parseXml       
        });
        };

        // show loading box on start of ajax call

        $('.notifyWindow').ajaxStart(function() {
        $('.refreshFeed').hide("fast");
        $('.notifyWindow').hide();
        $('.ajaxErrorBox').hide();
        $('.loadingNotifications').show("fast");

        });

        // hide loading box after ajax call has stopped

        $('.notifyWindow').ajaxStop(function() {
        $('.loadingNotifications').hide("slow");
        $('.refreshFeed').show("fast"); 

        });

        $('.notifyWindow').ajaxError(function() {
        $('.loadingNotifications').hide("slow");
        $('.ajaxErrorBox').show("fast");
        $('.refreshFeed').show("fast"); 
        });  

    // parse the feed/ xml file and append results to notifications div

    function parseXml (xml) {
        console.log("xml parsing begining");        
        if (jQuery.browser.msie)
        {
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
            xml = xmlDoc;
        }


    $(xml).find("entry").each(function()
    {

    var $item = $(this);
    var title = $item.find("title").text();
    var linkN = $item.find("link").attr("href");
    var output = "<a href='" + linkN + "' target='_self'>" + title + "</a><br />";
    $(".notifyWindow").append($(output)).show();

    });
    }



        }
else {
    console.log("notifications not available");
    return false;
}

});
```

If the DOM element exists I then try and call the getFeed function "getFeed();" however it comes back undefined. If anyone could shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `id` of an element is `view<portlet:namespace/>:editSplash`?! It's not a valid [name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).

Comment: it is a valid name - i am working with portlets and that is the name space to retrive dom elements in jsf. cheers

Comment: What do you mean with *it comes back undefined*? That the function `getFeed` is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - I moved my functions outside of the if statement. We live and learn lol :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're calling `getFeed` before it is defined. Try moving the if statement to after the function definition. Note that this behaviour is actually implementation specific, so some browsers may work this way and some may not.

Oh - And seriously? `view<portlet:namespace/>:editSplash` for an id?

Comment: yep working with jsf portlets therefore to identify dom elements you need to use the portlets name space e.g. http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portlet+namespace;jsessionid=C2CD75F96318975D6BC68820A29D0B22.node-1

Thanks for taking time to answer my question - i have solved the porblem see below - moved functions outside of the if statements as they were not in scope.

Comment: It's not the scope per se - it's the execution order that causes trouble.